# Alternate between several select elements depending on selection of other element with maximum speed/efficiency

Tags: jquery, html, shadow-dom

I've been hearing about this "shadow DOM" thing lately, and how it is a better way to manipulate DOM elements because using it doesn't require you to remove or add elements, rather you can just move them into and out of the shadow DOM (or something like that).

I have a select element with a few options in it. Depending on the chosen option I would like to change a second select (id="select2"?) completely. The versions of the second select are all completely different than each other.

I could load all those versions into jQuery objects and alternate between them depending on the selection in the first dropdown, and that would probably work just fine. But I would like to explore the shadow DOM option.

How would I do that? Can jQuery help me?

Would the second select always have the same id or does each shadow select have its own id, and so the id of the second select would change?

Here is some sample HTML:

```
<table id="maintable">
<thead>
<th>1st select</th>
<th>2nd Select</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<select id="select1">
<option value="opt1">Option 1</option>
<option value="opt2">Option 2</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<select id="select2" name="dependent_options">
<option value="do1">Do this</option>
<option value="do2">Do that</option>
</select>
</td>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Other select to replace `select2` with in the table above:

```
<select id="select2a" name="dependent_options"><!-- change id to select2a or keep the same as select2? -->
<option value="do3">Do a third thing</option>
<option value="do4">Do a 4th thing</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Most people just use `.hide()` and `.show()`, no need to move things.

Comment: @Barmar so you're saying I should add all the `<select>` elements into the same DOM node and just hide all but one of them?

Comment: Yes, that's a common way to do it.

Comment: @Barmar thanks. That initially seemed gross to me, but I'm warming up to it.

Comment: The nice thing about this is that you can see everything in the DOM inspector, and you can see which should be displayed based on their `style` attributes.